# How can I get specific values from a list within lists, inside a dictionary, and based on the keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hey there programmers i'm a bit new...

I have a dictionary containing many lists within lists and in the program I am asking the user for an input of a specific year this year will correlate directly to the keys of the dictionairy (I must find the user input in the keys of the dictionary) then once the specific key is found I must print that specific key along with some of the information/values within the key which is in the form of a list of lists.

In this example I will use a much smaller sample size of the problem but hopefully it will work on a huge data set:

```
dicti = {'1980': [['1','Emily', '800'], ['2','Steve', '20'],['3','france', '80']], '2000': [['1','jan', '8'],['2','aug', '0'], ['3','Ernest', '90']], 
'2003': [['1','mul', '40'],['2','Inuyasha', '20'],['3','hulk', '50'],['4','pop smoke', '1'],['5','kendrick', '2'],['6','nick', '1']],
 '2006'[['1','roger', '800'],['2','orochimaru', '1'], ['3', 'john', '783']]}
```

The output if the user enters 2003 should look something like this:

```
you selected 2003:
1.   mul: 40
2.   inuyasha: 20
3.   hulk: 50
4.   pop smoke: 1
5.   kendrick: 2
6.   nick: 1
```

I attempted the problem using this code:

```
yr = input('Enter yr: ')
for i in dicti.get(yr):
    for value in dicti[year]:
        print(val)
```

but this code produces:

```
1.   mul: 40
2.   inuyasha: 20
3.   hulk: 50
4.   pop smoke: 1
5.   kendrick: 2
6.   nick: 1
1.   mul: 40
2.   inuyasha: 20
3.   hulk: 50
4.   pop smoke: 1
5.   kendrick: 2
6.   nick: 1
1.   mul: 40
2.   inuyasha: 20
3.   hulk: 50
4.   pop smoke: 1
5.   kendrick: 2
6.   nick: 1
1.   mul: 40
2.   inuyasha: 20
3.   hulk: 50
4.   pop smoke: 1
5.   kendrick: 2
6.   nick: 1
```

It produces what I need but repeatedly and I only need it to print the info off once.

Comment: What have you attempted? Can we see some code? @That Guy

Comment: just edited it thank you I forgot to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
input_dict  = {
    '1980': [['1', 'Emily', '800'], ['2', 'Steve', '20'], ['3', 'france', '80']],
    '2000': [['1', 'jan', '8'], ['2', 'aug', '0'], ['3', 'Ernest', '90']],
    '2003': [['1', 'mul', '40'], ['2', 'Inuyasha', '20'], ['3', 'hulk', '50'], ['4', 'pop smoke', '1'],
             ['5', 'kendrick', '2'], ['6', 'nick', '1']],
    '2006': [['1', 'roger', '800'], ['2', 'orochimaru', '1'], ['3', 'john', '783']]}


user_input = input("Please select year: ")

if input_dict.get(user_input):
    for item in input_dict[user_input]:
        print(f"{item[0]}. {item[1]}: {item[2]}")
```

Output:

```
Please select year: 2003
1. mul: 40
2. Inuyasha: 20
3. hulk: 50
4. pop smoke: 1
5. kendrick: 2
6. nick: 1
```

Comment: Hey I checked! The only issue i'm running into with this solution is that it prints out multiples (it continually prints out the same information) For example: it will give me the first 6 and then print the first 6 off a couple more times I tried moving the print statement but then it just produces the last list and that's all.

Comment: @ThatGuy The Above mentioned output it prints. can you please verify it. That's what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my question above...

```
yr = input('enter yr: ')
for I in dicti[yr]:
    print(f'{I[0]}\t{I[1]}: {I[2]}')
```